# Unexpected resistor for oscillator

Tags: oscillator, crystal, stm32f10x

Please see these two part of [this board](https://www.olimex.com/Products/Duino/STM32/OLIMEXINO-STM32/resources/OLIMEXINO-STM32_Rev.A-schematic.pdf) :

[image: figure1]

In your opinion, What's the usage of the R32 resistor? also in the [AN2867 aplication note](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/application_note/CD00221665.pdf) has been mentioned:

[image: figure2]

Then we have to put a resistor to limit the inverter output current (I mean Rext). then What's really the usage of the R32 resistor?

An unrelated question, Should I always connect the RTC crystal(32.768Hz) to the ground?(I mean the shield of it)

Comment: If RF exists in the specific part on that circuit, then R32 may be unnecessary. Both supply a bias voltage to guarantee the oscillator will start. Either the designer was being cautious, or he has experience that RF is sometimes inadequate with his choice of crystal, or - possibly - the processor's errata indicates that some versions of the silicon omitted RF.

Comment: Haha, it's STM32F103, right? It's datahsheet shows it has internal RF already. But don't know why it sometimes need a external one to make it work!!! Especially for 12pF crystals, it's a **notorious** problem with STM32F103. In our products, once there are 30%'s board can't work well (although we've use 6pF crystal with them) without the external RF. Maybe the external RF only used to generate some **noise**, who knows!

Comment: @diverger 12pf crystals? what do you mean?

Comment: @Roh : most crystals cut for series resonance are calibrated to run at the right frequency at a specific capacitance, and labelled that way. In Diverger's case, 12pf. At other capacitance, they will still run, but at (slightly) the wrong frequency - 11ppm is about 1 second per day, and you can de-tune a crystal several times that.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Ah, Yeah Brian. that's right. I got it.

Comment: @Roh: I mean the crystal's load capacitance is 12pF or 6pF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R32 (the resistor in parallel with the crystal and forming feedback from output to input of the inverting amplifier) is vital to provide negative feedback at DC - this sets the bias point of the inverter into its linear area hence it can amplify the AC signal through the crystal and produce oscillation based on the crystal's frequency. Without R32 the input is not biased correctly and oscillations are at best sporadic and at worst non-existent.

The resistor in series with the output is needed (whether it is internal or not) to produce an overall 180 degrees phase shift from output to input. The phase shift caused by this resistor and the capacitor CL2 is a part of the picture with the other phase shift coming from the crystal itself and CL1.

Regarding the grounding of the crystal's case, I always do this as it adds a little more EMI protection.

Comment: +1 nice answer. I'm searching to find where you have closed the first parenthesis? :)

Comment: OK fix on its way LOL

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the kind of inverting amplifier you are using.

- case 1: If the active unit has a finite output resistance rout (medium-to-high valued) the additional resistor is indeed not required (however, it may be included - and it influences the time constant for CL2).
- case 2: If, however, the inverter is realized with an opamp (low output resistance rout with an unknown value) such a resistor is necessary to determine the associated time constant. Think, for example, of an ideal opamp inverter with zero output resistance - the capacitor CL2 would be useless because it would act simply as a load without any influence on the feedback path.
- Additional explanation: The working principle of the oscillator circuit is based on a feedback path consisting of a third-order lowpass. This lowpass contains a first order lowpass section (the first two elements) in series with a second-order L-C lowpass. (The inductance L is realized with the crystal). This 3rd-order lowpass is able to produce the necessary phase shift of -180deg at fixed frequency (as required by the Barkhausen criterion).

Comment: This appears to explain the role of series resistor Rext very nicely, but the question was about R32, in parallel with Q1.

Comment: Yes - you are right. It was my impression that the question was related to Rext. My fault.

Comment: IMO it's still a useful answer though.

Comment: On the other hand - the given explanation for Rext ("to limit the inverter output current") is a bit too general (not to say: too simple).

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent circuit of a crystal is basically a combination of series and parallel LC circuit with some resitance affecting it [Q-factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor) (very small series resitance or very high parallel resistance).

The very high Q-factor (e.g. 10^5; i.e. series R very low/parallel R very high) is good for a small frequency bandwidth (desired) but bad for starting the oszillation.

An additional external (high) parallel resistance assists to start the oszillation more readily and reliable.